# Web Worker asking variable value to main process

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I want to execute the logic and operation of a complex calculus in a web worker.

I need to ask, from the web-worker, for a variable value that is only available in the main process.

To simplify what I am asking:

Let's imagine that you have 2 variables in main process "a" and "b"

I want to execute in main process the following code, only sending "a" value:

```
worker.postMessage(a)
```

In the worker the logic will be something like:

```
if (a<10) {
  postMessage('result is true');
} else {
  b = "ask to main process the value of b"
  if (a*b < 20 ) {
      postMessage('result is true');
  } else {
      postMessage('result is false');
  }
}
```

One possible solution would be having a websocket open in the main process answering the value of variables, but I would like to know if there is any simpler or smarter solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I just found: https://github.com/nolanlawson/promise-worker allowing communication with Web Workers using Promises

I guess that with this package plus using Async/Await will solve my issue, isn't it?

Can you tell me if this is right? I am quite newe in javascript